# Both players turn around at the same time

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking, mirror-networking

i got the main camera following the players but once a player rotate to left or right the other player would do it too at the same time. I noticed that the event happens on void Turning() (on the player movement script)

```
public class CameraFollowMultiplayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The position that that camera will be following.
    public Transform playerTransform;
    // The speed with which the camera will be following.
    public float smoothing = 5f;
    // reference to mini map camera object
    public GameObject minimap;
    // The initial offset from the target.
    Vector3 offset;
    void Start()
    {
        // Calculate the initial offset.
        {
        
            offset = transform.position - playerTransform.position;
    }
}

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Create a postion the camera is aiming for based on the offset from the target.
        {
            Vector3 targetCamPos = playerTransform.position + offset;

        // Smoothly interpolate between the camera's current position and it's target position.
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetCamPos, smoothing * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("MiniMap"))
        {
            // Toggle minimap
            minimap.SetActive(!minimap.activeInHierarchy);
        }
        if (playerTransform != null)
        {
            transform.position = playerTransform.position + offset;
        }

    }

    public void setTarget(Transform target)
    {
        playerTransform = target;
    }
}
```

That is the script attached to the maincamera.

And this is my player movement script.

```
public override void OnStartLocalPlayer()
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollowMultiplayer>().setTarget(gameObject.transform);
        }
    }

void Turning()
        
    {
            if (isLocalPlayer)
            {
                // Create a ray from the mouse cursor on screen in the direction of the camera.
                Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        // Create a RaycastHit variable to store information about what was hit by the ray.
        RaycastHit floorHit;

        // Perform the raycast and if it hits something on the floor layer...
        if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask))
        {
            // Create a vector from the player to the point on the floor the raycast from the mouse hit.
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;

            // Ensure the vector is entirely along the floor plane.
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

                // Create a quaternion (rotation) based on looking down the vector from the player to the mouse.
            
                    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
                
                // Set the player's rotation to this new rotation.
                playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
                Debug.Log("Sending Hola to Server!");
                Hola();
                
            }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you marked this with mirror-networking (unityscript is not used anymore btw), which of the code is executed on the server? How is your player handled movement across the network? And what has the `CameraFollowMultiplayer` to do with the question?

Comment: i havent made a network manager yet. Using mirror default manager.

But the player movement and animator are being synced server to client (observer), the network rigidbody and transform are being synced client to server

I just wanted to point out the CameraFollowMultiplayer just to see if there is something wrong with the camera script itself.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Since the problem is about the player, you should as well post the code / setup for how you spawn your player and editor settings of it. The best code examples are always a standalone runable version with the bare minimun. That way a lot of basic mistakes can be excluded (missing network identity, wrong instantiation, etc)

Comment: Please double check your usage of the *UnityScript* tag. As mentioned in the [UnityScript tag info](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/unityscript/info), it's for a legacy option that was removed in version 2017.2; you probably want the tags *Unity* and *C#* instead.